# Use sed to uncomment a line in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, bash, shell, config, zsh

I'm trying to write a little shell script to go through the steps needed to enable apache and php on a new install of Mountain Lion. The step I'm stuck on is going into `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and uncommenting this line: `#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

From googling around so far I think sed is the way this would be done, but I can't get the syntax right. I tried this:

```
cd /etc/apache2
sudo sed -i '/s/#LoadModule php5_module libexec\/apache2\/libphp5.so/LoadModule php5_module libexec\/apache2\/libphp5.so' httpd.conf
```

which I thought would replace the commented line (escaping the slashes) with the uncommented line. But when I run that, I just get the following message back, and no result in the file:

`sed: 1: "httpd.conf": extra characters at the end of h command`

I'm out of my depth here with this type of scripting, how do I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 6):

You can use comma.

```
sed -i 's,#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so,LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so,g'
```

or

```
sed -i 's,#\(LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so\),\1,g' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first `/`:

```
sed -i 's/...'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is yet another way:

```
sudo sed -i '/#LoadModule php5_module libexec\/apache2\/libphp5.so/s/#//' httpd.conf
```

Comment: That gives me the same error as before... I must be doing something else wrong

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax is

```
's/#LoadModule php5_module libexec\/apache2\/libphp5.so/LoadModule php5_module libexec\/apache2\/libphp5.so/'
```

slash / can be change by another character (- for example) to avoid escaping slashes
dot . must be escaped in the pattern (left part) otherwise it means any character

```
's-#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5\.so-LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so-'
```